# Illegal access Javascript error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

I have sporadically been getting an "illegal access" exception in Chrome (29 and 30). Others have also seen this. It seems to happen on one specific line:

[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Here, `this` is an object I defined. It has a property `end` which is `null` or a number.

Does anyone know of anything that could cause an error *with that message* in Chrome?

EDIT: I don't expect anyone to debug ten thousands of lines of my code. What could cause an error with *that message*, whether it be jumping off the moon, singing blues, etc?

There are no occurrences of "illegal" in all of the Javascript code on the page.

---

This error has not happened in later versions of Chrome (31+).

Hopefully this is gone for good.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `delete ret['e']` that's causing the problem? Does the property `e` exist in the `ret` object?

Comment: Well, the Chrome Dev Tools says that it is `this.end`. And the previous line is ` var ret = {'s':this.start, 'e':this.end, 'n':0, 'v':this.val};`. And even if it didn't exist, it shouldn't throw and error; it should merely return false.

Comment: Can we get some context on how `this` is being created? Is this in a constructor? Is a unicorn's pee rainbow coloured? Hoping for at least 2 answers.

Comment: Well, whatever it is it's repeated 138 times. Perhaps that's a clue.

Comment: Are using a framework or webkit of some kind or are you writing this pure javascript. The uncaught illegal access error usually means you are trying to parse something that is NULL.  -edit- IMHO this.end === null  over == also.

Comment: @tremor `this.end === null ` is not the same, as `== null` checks for both `null` and `undefined`. Paul, are you sure `this` is not a host object?

Comment: Try to wrap delete ret['e'] with a try...catch and tell us what you get.

Comment: Maybe this was an issue with v8. It looks like that error pops up a few times the [v8 changelog](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/ChangeLog). It also seems to be an issue others were having with chrome around the same time.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2443, this would help:

```
try {
   delete ret['e'];
} catch (e) {} // do nothing
```

Answer (score -2):

We can't be sure, but depending on your network speed, hardware, your DOM wasn't totally and perfectly loaded.

You was probaby using recursion, many of them, with some hard javascript computation on each.

What happened is all tags and scripts of the DOM was already loaded and parsed, so the script started anyway. But content data not fully.
The javascript addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded", ) is more watching tags and their good closures to start his job, instead of the real full data load.

This behavior is possible on other browsers.

While your script was for sure too loud on his time, the javascript engine on all browsers had evolved enough to handle it smoothly, mostly on the memory part which was clearly the funnel.